# mysqli method calling order

Tags: php, mysqli

I know that from the php manual that **bind_result** must be after **execute** and prior to calling **fetch**.

Ide like to know where or if where the correct order to place **store_result** currently i have being calling pria to bind_results.

```
$psl -> execute();
$psl -> store_result(); // ?
$psl -> bind_result($val);
$psl -> fetch();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must call `store_result()` after calling `execute()` if you wish to retrieve the number of rows returned from the query.  See this for more information:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

To clarify, I have always called `store_result()` just after calling `execute()`.  I am not sure if you can call it after binding the results, but perhaps someone else will be able to clarify that.

Comment: I have called store_result after bind_result method and it still worked, no err notices in the php-error log. Like you said Pete171 ill wait to see there's more clarification method calling order.